# While washing my hair, I ___ it with my hands

Tags: vocabulary

I want to say that when I wash my head, I move my hand and fingers in a way that hair gets tangled.

What should be the word?

> While washing my hair, I ___ it with my hands.

Can't use the word tangle because that's not my intention.
I do something with my hands that it gets tangled.

Comment: You tangled it, whether intentionally or not. Or, you could say you *got it tangled*.

Comment: Can you edit the question to explain a bit? I thought that perhaps you're thinking that "I tangle it with my hands" means that you entangle your hands *into* your hair, and when you say "that's not my intention" you mean "that's not the meaning I want." Others are taking "that's not my intention" to mean that the tangling is accidental, and that you're under the impression that "tangle" can only be used if you mean to tangle something. There are confusions to correct either way, but please edit to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

English has many verbs that can express an intentional or an unintentional act (e.g., "drop," "lose," "forget").  In some languages, these are carefully distinguished or can be systematically distinguished, but that is not generally true of English, where there is no systematic way to signal this distinction.  "I tangle my hair" could either refer to an intentional act or an unintentional and undesirable result.

In this case, I might say: "I get my hair tangled (by my hands)" to help signal that the result is undesirable and unintentional.  This structure, however, can also sometimes be used to describe intentional acts, such as "getting your hair washed."   In the context, it would be clear that the result of tangling was unintentional and undesired.

Either "with my hands" or "by my hands" could be used to express the instrument that causes the tangling; however using "with" in this case is ambiguous because it could also be read as a complement of the verb "tangle," indicating what the hair is getting tangled with.

Answer (score 2):

The tangling effect is completely unintentional.

So you really just want to describe the motion with your hands.  What you do is "massage" your scalp.

> While washing my hair I massage my scalp (with my hands).

The "with my hands" phrase is probably unnecessary; what else could you use?